# Remove the Last 31 Days SQL Query in BigQuery not working due to date format

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have in a BigQuery Table the date in the folowing format:

Date
2020-07-15

I´m trying to use this query to remove the last 31 days:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT*
FROM
  `dataset.Raw_.Data`
WHERE
 DATE(Date) <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

Unfortunally is not woking, and I believe the reason is the format of the date in the Bigquery table. This is the error I get:

> No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: DATE.
> Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(DATETIME);
> DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64) at [6:2]

=> Is it any way to modify the sql-query to remove the last 31 days without modifying the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing dates as strings, you should be able to just `cast()`:

```
WHERE CAST(Date as date) <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

If you have a date already, then no need to `cast()`:

```
WHERE Date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per error message - your Date field is already of DATE data type so you can just use below

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT *
FROM
  `dataset.Raw_.Data`
WHERE
 Date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
```

Comment: I still get this error:" No matching signature for operator <= for argument types: DATETIME, DATE. Supported signatures: ANY <= ANY at [6:2]"

Comment: Previous Error message and the new one  - contradict each other! What is the data type of your Date field?!